# How can I stop Hard disk spinning when bluetooth audio is played for NAS content?

Tags: hard-drive, audio, windows-8.1, bluetooth, windows-media-player

I am keeping music folders on NAS drive and synced those to laptop through windows file synchronization. When playing these media files through WMP/VLC while redirecting output through bluetooth, HDD starts spinning at very high speed. Disk usage goes to 100% on constant basis.

Its a dell Inspiron 15 3521 laptop with BT 4.0 and SATA 5400 500 GB HDD. There is around 70 GB free space in HDD C drive and this spinning does not happen when playing media on WMP via USB headphone, audio jack or laptop speaker.

Disk usage in task manager shows that system and "mcafee on-access scanner service" are using it for maximum time. System being at top means some driver seems to be responsible. Average response time for HDD also goes from under 1000 ms to above 2000 ms.

I tried playing youtube as well as local media files. Disk usage still goes upto 100%, so it seems like Bluetooth issue. How can I be sure?

Answer (score 1):

If there's disk usage then there's also quite likely (some) CPU usage. Download and run [Process Explorer](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx), double-click the `System` process, and go to `Threads`. Then sort the threads by CPU usage. The culprit thread should be among those that are using the CPU. If you're lucky, its `Start Address` will contain the driver's filename.